# Upload file to AWS s3 without backend only flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart, amazon-s3, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to upload a video on s3 but nothing works.
Moreover, we can do it using the native code of iOS and Android and connect it using the flutter channel. But It seems too expensive in terms of time and complexity.

We have another way that we can send the media file to our backend server and from the server side, we can upload it to the S3 bucket.

But I'm trying to figure out a way to do this from the front-end side itself.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Use S3 presigned URLs, your backend issues the URLs, the frontend uses the URL to directly upload to S3.

Comment: Ultimately the issue is credentials.  Do you want the credentials you use to upload to be available in the front end?  They are likely somewhat hidden but a determined person could still find them.  As @luk2302 indicated, the backend should generate a URL to use.

Comment: how i can upload video on s3 without backend with presigned url

Comment: i'm successful to upload video on s3 but it's not presigned can any one help me with that